# Setting up a Digital Rights management system with mysql (linux) and c# (windows)

Tags: c#, mysql, drm

I am creating a piece of software that can be used in robotics. I would like to add some Digital RIghts Management (DRM) and i have an idea. I wanna create my exe file for windows using my normal c# visual studio programming. This is the program i sell to people along with a license key. I then would like this program to "call" my server when the program is first started to activate the product to check if it has a license or not. I would like the login and password to the server to be read only. so my program can only read data from the mysql server and not write to it and i would like this connection to be encrypted. This is for added security so if anybody is able to reverse engineer the login and password they will not be able to do anything else than read the database.

So my questions are:

1) Can i connect to a mysql server using a url like stackoverflow.com or do i have to use a ip adress?

2) Is it possible to encrypt this connection somehow?

3) Is it possible to make a username and password for a mysql server that can only read data from the server and not write to it?

4) Is it safe to have a mySQL server with a root password on the net?

These questions might seem stupid but I am not that good at programming. Any pointers in any directions would be appreciated, you don't have to explicitly answer every question.

Comment: You'd be much better off to expose a web service. I don't have time to write that entire answer right now, but look up creating a webapi service

Comment: This is a *question and answer* site, not a *many questions, many answers* site. Please take a few minutes to review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to=ask). The whole site is designed to work around the concept of a single question per post that can be definitively answered. You've posted 4, which means that separate people can answer each one individually, and there's no way to accept a single answer as the definitive one. (It's also more about configuring your server than about programming, which makes it off-topic here according to the [help] guidelines.)

Comment: I see. This is the second time i asked something bad. I tried to be really specific. I will definetely remember the one question rule from now on. I have a hard time destingusing between configuring a server and programming. Sorry for asking another bad question and thanks to Dan Drews for giving me a pointer in the right direction. again sorry.

Comment: It seems you are looking for a  method to protect your software. You may try to search some other method , such as Software Licensing and Protection Services etc. Because DRM is mainly used to protect Video/Audio/Document, such as PlayReady/OMA/WideVine (different DRM solution) according to my understand.

Comment: Thanks for you input Eric. I am looking into a software licensing called QLM from soraco. It looks really easy to use. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)